# ¿Existe jerarquía de carpetas en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, filesystem

mi duda es sencilla... o eso creo.

Estoy creando mi propio tema y me gustaría saber si dentro del directorio raíz existe además de la jerarquía de carpetas básica de la instalación, otra jerarquía "personalizada" o algo similar, por ejemplo, alguna carpeta donde pueda almacenar mis plantillas de categorías personalizadas y mantener un orden dentro de mi directorio raíz.

Siguiendo algunos tutoriales para entender un poco el mundillo de wordpress he visto que se puede crear una carpeta llamada `template-parts` y `page-templates`, que de hecho estoy usando, pero más allá de eso en mi caso en particular `requiero de una carpeta` `para guardar mis plantillas de categorías personalizadas` (que son muchas).

Entonces:

¿Existe algún `category-template` o alguna carpeta similar que se pueda crear? ¿De que manera puedo organizar un poco mejor todos los archivos que tengo en mi directorio raíz?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe tal cosa en wordpress para los temas, la carpeta page-templates en realidad solo guarda archivos php que son llamados por otros archivos, por ende, puedes crear una carpeta que se llame category-templates que guarde cosas como el contenido de un loop y llamar a ese archivo desde el archivo category.php principal para no repetir código, por lo que también puedes crear una para plantillas personalizadas, sin embargo, no puedes meter un category.php dentro de una carpeta porque wordpress no lo podría localizar, pero si hacer una llamada dentro de category.php hacia una carpeta con un include por ejemplo